# Use signs in the numerator and denominator to find intervals where $f(x)>0$

Tags: calculus

Let

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 -4x + 4}{x - 1}$$

and use its graph below to confirm your answers to the following question.

**Question**.  Use the signs in the numerator and denominator of $f(x)$ to find out in which interval $f(x)>0$.

**Trouble**.  This is most likely about the quotient rule for derivatives.  Perhaps I haven't understood the words in the question.  I don't know what it is asking me.

The graph of $f(x)$:

[image: The graph of (x^2 -4x + 4)/(x - 1).]

Comment: The problem is asking for the interval where $f(x)$ is positive. It's also telling you exactly how to determine that, and it has nothing to do with derivatives.

Comment: Are you familiar with the technique of completing the square?  Use that technique on the numerator.

Comment: @RobertShore, thank you.  Yes, I'm not too bad with completing the square.  That makes sense now.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$f(x) = \frac{x^2 -4x + 4}{x - 1}$$

$$f(x) = \frac{(x-2)^2}{x - 1}$$

Since $(x-2)^2\ge 0$

If $f<0$ it means the denominator $x-1<0$, therefore,

$$x<1$$

Comment: Thank you!  I had not understood the comments until I saw your answer.  Very appreciated.

Comment: Great, glad it helps.